# Optimizing a normalized estimator for a linear channel

Tags: random-variables, linear-transformations, nonlinear-optimization, parameter-estimation

Assume $y=Hx+n$, how to design an optimal linear filter $W$ such that $$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\|x^{\dagger}Wy\|^2}{\|Wy\|^2}\right)$$ is maximized, where $\frac{Wy}{\|Wy\|}$ can be reviewed as a normalized estimator of $x$.

Conditions:

$H$ is a known matrix of size $M\times N$ ($M\leq N$);

$x$ (of size $N\times 1$) is an unknown but deterministic vector;

$y$ (of size $M\times 1$) is the observations;

and $n$ is AWGN with noise power $N_0$.

The expectation is taken over noise $n$ (one can also assume that $x$ is random and then the expectation is also taken over $x$).

Note 1: This problem is close to, but not exactly the same as an LMMSE estimate, while in the latter case we have
$$W=H^{\dagger}/\left(HH^{\dagger}+N_0 I\right).$$

Note 2: When $N_0\!\to\!0$, the LMMSE becomes optimal since in this case
$$W=H^{\dagger}/\left(HH^{\dagger}\right),$$
and
$$Wy=x.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{\|x^{\dagger}Wy\|^2}{\|Wy\|^2}=\frac{\|x\|^4}{\|x\|^2}=\|x\|^2,$$
which attains the maximum by noting that 
$$\frac{\|x^{\dagger}Wy\|^2}{\|Wy\|^2}\leq\frac{\|x\|^2\|Wy\|^2}{\|Wy\|^2}=\|x\|^2.$$

Comment: can you describe the size of matrices and vectors involved? Does this estimator need to be unbiased or only the mentioned metric must be optimized? It's the quotient of two gamma variables (chi square to be specific). So we need to maximize the mean of the beta distribution, result from fraction of two norms.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald: The estimator does not need to be unbiased, and only the maximization is of interest.